# How to whitelist an iframe and script of some other source embeded/ called by an iframe that is whitelisted in the CSP?

Tags: content-security-policy, iframe

For example I am having an iframe with src `https://iframe1.com` which is listed in my content security policy. If the whitelisted iframe calls some iframe from another source like `https://iframe2.com`, will the content security policy block the iframe?

For example I am having an iframe with src `https://iframe1.com` which is listed in my content security policy. If the whitelisted iframe calls some script from another source like `https://thirdparty/script.js`, will the content security policy block the script?

If it is going to block it, how do I whitelist the script and iframe?

I know 'strict-dynamic' whitelists scripts if it is generated from whitelisted root script. Does it whitelist the script if it is generate from whitelisted frame source also?